# C# : Checking if an object (who has a min and max property) falls between any existing objects? Explained inside

Tags: c#, linq, c#-3.0

I wonder if anyone can help?

I have a list with a collection of objects, each object has a min and max property.

So imagine i have

```
 id : 1
 min : 10
 max : 49

 id : 2
 min : 50
 max : 69

 id : 3
 min : 70
 max : 89
```

I should NOT be allowed to create a new object that is like so.

```
 id : 4
 min : 88
 max : 91
```

as this falls within a range of what i have already. (it overlaps id 3) Hence no overlapping ranges.

I did try to solve it like so, but it isn't working

```
    var test =
            myObjects.FindAll(
                o => myMinVal.Value >= o.Min && myMaxVal.Value <= o.Max).ToList();
```

So basically if test is NOT null, means i have an overlap.

I have tried reversing the greater than and less than signs....

Any ideas how i would get this to work?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Also take for example this object, which also SHOULD fail as although it doesn't clash any specific 1 object! it clashes when you look at the 3 original.

```
 id : 4
 min : 5
 max : 91
```

I hope this makes sense

Comment: Doesn't your 3rd object's range overlap the second's or am I missing something?

Comment: my id 4 will overlap id 3...  i have edited the question a bit.. basically id 1,2,3 are fine and exist already but i should be allowed to create id 4 as it overlaps 3... I have been looking for a formulae for this / way of doing it ... and i am coming up blank

Comment: Martin, I'm confused by your comment about the object id=4. You said this falls within a range of what you have already (overlaps id 3), then you say "Hence no overlapping ranges". Can you clarify? Most of us are puzzled by what you wrote...

Comment: FindAll returns a list, you don't need to do .ToList()

Comment: Yes code4life you were right i forgot the import word NOT.. See edit... but its this line "I should NOT be allowed to create a new object that is like so."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not checking enough things.

Basically you need to see if either the min is in the range, or if the max is in the range of any objects.  Here's a unit test w/ the working lambda:

```
[TestClass]
public class Overlap
{

    List<TestData> data = new List<TestData>
    {
        new TestData { Id = 1, Min = 10, Max= 49},
        new TestData { Id =2, Min=50, Max=69},
        new TestData { Id=3, Min = 70, Max = 89}
    };

    [TestMethod]
    public void BoundaryCheck()
    {
        var mydata = new TestData { Id=4, Min=69, Max=100};

        bool fail = data.Any(d => (d.Min <= mydata.Min && d.Max >= mydata.Min) || 
                                  (d.Max >= mydata.Max && d.Min <= mydata.Max));

        Assert.IsTrue(fail);
    }

    class TestData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Min { get; set; }
        public int Max { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect Paul, yep i needed to test more things..!! thanks... with your test it now works! thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like that:

```
class Interval {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Min { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; } 
}
```

Two extension methods for checking whether interval overlaps with other intervals or any of multiple intervals:

```
public static bool Overlaps(this Interval interval, Interval targetInterval) {
    return interval.Min <= targetInterval.Max && 
               interval.Max >= targetInterval.Min;
}

public static bool Overlaps(this Interval interval, IEnumerable<Interval> targetIntervals) {
    return targetIntervals.Any(t => interval.Overlaps(t));
}
```

Usage:

```
var interval = new Interval { Min = 5, Max = 15 };
bool isOverlapping = interval.Overlaps(intervalList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't

```
myMinVal.Value >= o.Min
```

Be

```
myMinVal.Value <= o.Min
```

Edit -

This doesn't work?

```
var isValid = myObjects
               .Where(o => myMinVal.Value >= o.Min && myMaxVal.Value <= o.Max)
               .Any();
```

Comment: If that's not backwards, then your Max one is!

Comment: I have tried this way too, but i can always get it to accept the values when there is an overlap

Comment: that was a typo, i have edited the question.. But i have tried it every which way i can think of and i can always get it to accept the new object when in fact there is an overlap.